# How to present a popoverPresentationController from custom UICollectionViewCell NIB

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, nib, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I have a popover that was defined in a `UIViewController`, but now needs to be presented from a custom `UICollectionViewCell`. The `present` is no longer working as the class is a `UICollectionViewCell` and no longer a UIViewController. How do I present the popover from the custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
   @IBAction func period(_ sender: Any) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ScoreClockPopoverViewController", bundle: nil)
        let scoreClockPopoverViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScoreClockPopoverViewController") as! ScoreClockPopoverViewController

        scoreClockPopoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

        let popover = scoreClockPopoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!
        popover.delegate = self
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = .any
        popover.sourceView = periodButton
        popover.sourceRect = periodButton.bounds


        present(scoreClockPopoverViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)
       //Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'present'

    }
```

If I try to extend the `UICollectionViewCell` as a `UIViewContoller` I get the following error: `Extension of type 'HeaderCollectionViewCell' cannot inherit from class 'UIViewController'`

Comment: Probably you want to have your `period()` action "call back" to the View Controller, and let the View Controller handle loading and presenting the Popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `CollectionViewcontroller` as Delegate of your `CollectionViewCell`.

When the period function on your CollectionViewCell is called, call the "didClickPeriod" function (that you create yourself) of the cell's delegate.

Include this e.g. in your cell

```
protocol HeaderCollectionViewCellDelegate {
    func didClickPeriod(sender: Any)
}
```

make sure the cell has a property

```
var delegate: HeaderCollectionViewCellDelegate!
```

Notice the !. Assuming you instantiate from Storyboard you can't pass your delegate on instantiation but have to fill it "manually". The ! basically states that you can work with this property as if it is always set - assuming you fill the property properly, this will save you from unwrapping all the time. If you don't, you'll receive a crash.

In your period function simply do

```
@IBAction func period(_ sender: Any) {
   self.delegate.didClickPeriod(sender)
}
```

In your `CollectionViewController` make sure it implements the protocol e.g. by including

```
extension YourCollectionViewController: HeaderCollectionViewCellDelegate {
    func didClickPeriod(sender: Any) {
        // your previous presentation logic. 
        // But now you're in the CollectionViewController so you can do
       ...
       present(scoreClockPopoverViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  However, I'm getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` as delegate is nil.  I tried to add `delegate = self as? HeaderCollectionViewCellDelegate` to `override func awakeFromNib() {` but it's still nil.

Comment: Added delegate = self in the wrong place, added it to `CollectionViewcontroller`

Comment: Thats what i meant